# The lifespan of memory allocated by the malloc() function

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

If I pass to a function a pointer where the pointer gets an address to allocated memory, is the memory freed when the function exits?

```
void initWomenList(Women **head, Women *headWoman) {        
  headWoman = (Women *) malloc(sizeof(Women));
  if (headWoman == NULL) {
      printf("Allocation of headWoman failed\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  headWoman->userWoman = NULL;
  headWoman->next = NULL;

  head = &headWoman;
}
```

Are both head and headWoman NULL when the function returns?

Comment: `head` and `headWoman` don’t *exist* when the function returns.

Comment: head exist it is just headWoman that do not

Comment: You could be interested by [Boehm's conservative GC](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/): you would do `GC_MALLOC` instead of `malloc` and you don't care about `free`-ing memory

Comment: @gbox: No, the `Women**` that is `head` certainly does not exist.  Maybe its referent does (but not in your code as written).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no automatic memory deallocation (sometimes called *garbage collector*) in the C language. Any memory allocated with `malloc/calloc/realloc` must be manually freed using `free` function.

All function parameters in C language are passed by value, thus assigning `headWomen` inside function has no effect outside and currently you have *memory leak* because no pointer is holding allocated memory.

```
void
alloc_mem(int* a) {
    a = malloc(sizeof(*a));
}

//usage in your case
int* a;
//Function will allocate memory for single int, but it won't be saved to variable a.
alloc_mem(a);
```

Better is to either use *pointer-to-pointer* or return *pointer* from function.

```
int*
alloc_mem() {
    return malloc(sizeof(int));
}

//usage
int* a = alloc_mem();
if (a != NULL) {
    //Check if null
}
```

Or with *pointer-to-pointer* approach

```
void
alloc_mem(int** a) {
    *a = malloc(sizeof(**a));
}

//usage
int* a;
alloc_mem(&a);
if (a != NULL) {
    //Do the job.
}
```

At the end of all these operations, always call `free` function

```
free(a);
```

If I go back to your initial example, you have to rewrite function to something like this:

```
void 
//Notice here **headWoman instead of *headWoman
initWomenList(Women **head, Women **headWoman) {  
  //Notice here *headWoman instead of headWoman      
  *headWoman = malloc(sizeof(Women));
  if (headWoman == NULL) {
      printf("Allocation of headWoman failed\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  headWoman->userWoman = NULL;
  headWoman->next = NULL;

  //Notice here *head instead of head
  *head = &headWoman;
}
```

And usage:

```
Woman* headWoman;
Woman* head;

initWomenList(&head, &headWoman);
//Don't forget to free memory after usage.
```

Comment: Is there a way to solve it? to send head and get headWomen?

Comment: @gbox, it is a way, using *pointer-to-pointer* is one possibility.

Comment: But in my case it is a pointer to pointer that I am sending to the function